# Error when releasing android app with app actions

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-console, app-actions

I have implemented app actions according to the https://developers.google.com/assistant/app/overview

Now I am trying to release the .apk and I get the following error from google play:

> Failed to upload APKs: failed to upload app bundle, error: googleapi:
>   Error 403: APK contains an actions resource, but Actions on Google
>   terms of service not yet accepted.,
>   apkNotificationMessageKeyActionsTosNotAccepted

Does anyone face the same issue? Where can I accept the Actions on Google terms of service.

Comment: Please share a screenshot of the error log. In this description not clearly identify the issue,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try these two actions and keep us posted:

1. Submit your app through the [Deployment request form](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSc7y8W6GZbwN7tUecQVblnqbrOcBhAtoLmefZ6LkJr--SOSrA/viewform)
2. Accept Actions on Google consent under Pricing & Distribution in Play console

Comment: Anyone knows where is this consent hidden in the new Play Console? many thanks!

Answer (score 2):

**2021 - new Play console**

Try these steps:

- Fill the [form](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSc7y8W6GZbwN7tUecQVblnqbrOcBhAtoLmefZ6LkJr--SOSrA/viewform) and submit
- Open Play Console, select your application then find the `Advanced Settings` under `Settings` section.
- Click on `Actions on Google` tab and check the checkbox.

You can find more details here [Request review](https://developers.google.com/assistant/app/get-started#request-review) and [Prepare to deploy](https://developers.google.com/assistant/app/deployment)

Comment: `Settings` seems to have been renamed to `Setup` now

Answer (score 0):

Hi Could you try using the Change Android versionCode and versionName step to increment the version code with each build so this error will not come up? well at least I hope.

Comment: This is not a valid reason. if version code issue then play store clearly warn like

"Failed to upload apk, error: APK specifies a version code that has already been used"

Answer (score 0):

For accepting the Actions terms of condition, you might use the "old" version of goole play console. Then onwards, choose the app you are trying to deploy, and open the "Price and distribution" block. Then, scroll down until "Consent", and check and accept "Actions on Google" option.
That might let you sort out this issue.
[image: Enable Actions on Google]